# Sort array by its elements child

Tags: php, sorting

How to sort array by 'total'? I've tried `arsort($myArray["total"]);` but it returns null;

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Rnukir' (length=6)
      'total' => string '9m' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Arnesista' (length=9)
      'total' => string '1m 45s' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Omas' (length=8)
      'total' => string '1m 22s' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use one of the [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) variants and provide a callback that defines the order of your element.

The callback will be passed two elements which are currently compared. In your case that's an array of size 2 (containing the keys name and total). It has to return negative, 0 or a positive value to indicate if the first parameter should be sorted before, is equal to or should be sorted after the second parameter.

One possibility might be `strlen($a['total']) - strlen($b['total'])` (since I don't know how exactly you expect PHP to magically sort on your values of total).

Comment: Adn what's $a and $b?

Comment: The two parameters of your callback (cf. my second paragraph). It's explained in more depth on the usort docs page.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
usort($myArray, "compare");
```

Your callback function could look like this, if you want to sort it exactly:

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    // Get minutes and second from 'total' string
    $regular_expression = "/^(([0-9]{1,2})m )?([0-9]{1,2})s$/";
    if(preg_match($regular_expression, $a['total'], $matchA) != 1) return 0; // Invalid time string
    if(preg_match($regular_expression, $b['total'], $matchB) != 1) return 0; // Error handling

    // Calculate total amount of seconds
    $secondsA = 0;
    if(strlen($matchA[2]) > 0) $secondsA = 60 * (int)$matchA[2]; // Minutes
    if(strlen($matchA[2]) > 0) $secondsB = 60 * (int)$matchB[2];

    $secondsA += (int)$matchA[3]; // Seconds
    $secondsB += (int)$matchB[3]; 

    // Compare
    // Equal -> 0
    if ($secondsA == $secondsB) {
        return 0;
    }
    // A smaller than B -> -1
    // A higher than B -> 1
    return ($secondsA < $secondsB) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

PHP knows to use the "compare" function and automatically calls it with your array items. You don't need to do call the compare function yourself.
(Code is untested)

Comment: `usort` returns `bool true` and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
  0 =>array(
      'name' => 'Rnukir',
      'total' => '9m'),
  1 => array(
      'name' => 'Arnesista',
      'total' => '1m 45s'),
  2 => array(
      'name' => 'Omas',
      'total' => '1m 42s'),
  3 => array(
      'name' => 'John',
      'total' => '11m')
);

//1 - String value convert to time in second

$modified_array = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$each) {
    $each["total"] = stringToTime($each["total"]);
    $modified_array[$key] = $each;
}

//2 - Sort array based on second

usort($modified_array, "cmp");

//3 - Convert second to string

$final_array = array();
foreach($modified_array as $key=>$each) {
    $each["total"] = timeToString($each["total"]);
    $final_array[$key] = $each;
}

//4 - See output

print_r($final_array);


function stringToTime($str)
{
    $str_array = explode(" ",$str);
    $v = 0;
    foreach($str_array as $key=>$value) {
        $v  += substr($value,-1)=='m' ? substr($value,0,-1)*60 : substr($value,0,-1)*1;

    }
    return $v;
}

function timeToString($time)
{
    $m = intval($time/60);
    $s = $time%60;
    if(empty($s))
        return $m."m";
    else
        return $m."m ".$s."s";
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['total'] == $b['total']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in file on line `$b = $activityTimes[$key+1];` in `// if even number or 0` block

Comment: Where and how you are using $b = $activityTimes[$key+1]; This answer is working for any array values with minutes/seconds, just execute this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php

  $array = array(
  0 =>array(
      'name' => 'Rnukir',
      'total' => '1'),
  1 => array(
      'name' => 'Arnesista',
      'total' => '2'),
  2 => array(
      'name' => 'Omas',
      'total' => '3'),
  3 => array(
      'name' => 'John',
      'total' => '4')
);

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key]  = $row['name'];
    $total[$key] = $row['total'];
}
 print_r($total);


 array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $array);
//  array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $name, SORT_ASC $array);
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works and where you've got `$total`?